# 60s short story with an autonomous car in a population control tunnel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Not looking for “The Tunnel Ahead” by Alice Glaser. The 60's short story I’m looking for is about a single man who uses his car, with no steering wheel or pedals, to go on a picnic. On the way home the car takes him through a tunnel. Doors close and the occupants are liquefied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [60s short story, robot cars travel through a tunnel, occupants are liquefied](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141480/) - although the answer there isn't the one you seek, I reckon (from the phrasing, username and avatar) you are the same asker; in which case please don't repost questions you didn't get an answer to. Instead, follow [these instructions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to have both accounts merged, and [set a bounty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on the earlier question. All the best.

Comment: You've asked this question previously but have been logged out of your account since. Please follow the instructions [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts. Then you will be able to comment on the answer on your previous question and edit the question with any updated information.

Comment: FWIW though is there a reason you don't think this is "The Tunnel Ahead" as that seems to match perfectly?

Comment: “”The Tunnel Ahead” is about a family that goes to the beach. They are not trapped in the tunnel. I’m looking for the author & title of the one about a single man who goes on a picnic and *does* get liquified. 
Sorry I did this wrong. The first answer to my first question was very good, but I still need the author & title.

Comment: If you merge your accounts, as per the above, you should be able to edit your old question to add this detail in.