# Story about a theme park that can kill you

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a sci-fiction episode I saw on TV in 80s or 90s:

It is about a theme park. Every ride / food / attraction is free. However, you got to get some "ticket" before allowed to use any of the stuff. Getting the "tickets" has a certain probability that you are killed. The story is about a family visiting this special theme park.

Due to comments (and reading into each of the suggested stories) I am sure now:

The episode is based on [Spending a Day at the Lottery Fair](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49084)

I saw the corresponding sci-fi episode late at night in german television probably in the late 80s or early 90s.

Is there a way to find out what the name / publisher of the epsiode is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Carnival_(short_story) ? - oh you said a tv show

Comment: If this helps, I vaguely remember seeing or reading this also. There was a similar older story where cars caught in tunnels would be gassed -- population control in both stories but i doubt this sort of thing would work, anyway. Birth control is far more efficient.

Comment: @releseabe - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141480/60s-short-story-robot-cars-travel-through-a-tunnel-occupants-are-liquefied

Comment: There was a comic something like this - I think it was a Batman/Wonder Woman comic? - where a thinly veiled Disney World was used to kidnap random people so their life energy could be used to feed a thinly veiled Walt Disney ("Uncle Mort?").  Not the answer, and a really _bad_ comic, but it points out that killing/harvesting people at an amusement park is kind of a trope.

Comment: @NKCampbell , yes that is the story! But how to find the tv show/movie for that?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Story-identifaction questions are unwanted?

Comment: No, story-identification questions are on-topic. But this one is pretty short and sparse on detail, so [it's not the best type of story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394).

Comment: @Valorum: Thanks, that is the story. Totally silly way to try to reduce a population of 1 billion, of course. Just as Soylent Green is both a crazy way to reduce population (although voluntary euthanasia on demand is a great idea and is coming) and crazier way to address food shortages -- how many people could Edward G. Robinson plausibly feed?

Comment: I thought since I now know (thx NKCampbell !) the title it should be easy to find the corresponding tv episode but no success yet.

Comment: Most likely seems to be https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171793/title-of-dystopian-story-set-in-an-amusement-park?noredirect=1&lq=1. Except, no TV episode.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - that's why I went back and deleted my answer - I can't find any evidence that it was turned into a tv episode - even though OP says it's the correct story